# How to get my AE1000 adapter to work?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers

So I am so frustrated because my wireless netowrk is not getting picked up by my laptop so I put my AE1000 cisco adapter in it but it needs the driver to make it work! How do I get it to work? If you need more info please ask and I will give you what you need. Please help me!! :'(

my Verion is 12.04 ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Awesome question!  It took me a while to figure this out.  I know linked answers aren't preferred but this blog post is the only thing I've found with correct answer.  I'm posting this using my AE1000 right now.  :-)

[Compiling drivers for the Cisco AE1000](http://confignewton.com/?p=104)